# Recording desktop & game in the same video

Tags: display, video-capture, screen-recorder, fraps

I am trying to document a video game crash, I have Win7 and I tried using Fraps but I can only record either the desktop, or the game. But not both on the same video.

For example, if I start recording on the desktop and launch the game, the recorded video stops there. And if I start recording inside the video game, the video stops when the game crash, and it doesn't continue recording the desktop with the error message.

Which other software could I use to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can record your desktop between resolution switches with [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html)...

In VLC you'd need to go:

- Media > Convert / Save > Capture Device
- Choose "Desktop" as a capture mode
- Up the framerate to something reasonable, like 20fps.
- Click "Convert / Save".
- Choose a destination file. (Usually just navigating to documents and typing "foo.mpg" as a name)
- Click "Start"...

You simply click "Stop" to stop the video from recording.

You'll need to change the resolution of the game to something smaller than your screen (Or the same size) or else the video will be cut off when recording though.